# ObjectListView / TreeListView: Alternate background color by expandable section

Tags: colors, objectlistview, alternating, treelistview

I have a TreeListView control where each root item is expandable, containing an arbitrary number of subnodes. The background color should alternate only at the root level so that all subnodes are of the same background color. If I use a RowFormatter it works as long as it's not sorted by clicking the header.

```
    private void FormatRow(OLVListItem item)
    {
        var node = (BaseNode)item.RowObject;
        var root = node.GetRoot();
        if (root == null) return;

        var alternate = Model.GetNodeIndex(root) % 2 == 1;
        item.BackColor = alternate ? Color.FromArgb(240, 240, 240) : Color.White;
    }
```

How do I get the object's ACTUAL index in the tree, not the index in the underlying data?

Comment: You can get the actual index using `args.DisplayIndex`from the `FormatRowEventArgs`, but that won't really help, because each child object is based on the same index. Maybe you could apply the coloring after the content or sorting changed by iterating over all items and apply alternating color for each parent item.